# How can I open Notepad2 as my Git commit editor using the Diff Files syntax scheme?

Tags: git

I'm using [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) as my Git commit editor.  It has a command-line option to change the syntax scheme, like so:

```
notepad2.exe /s Diff Files
```

I'm using verbose commits in Git, and I want to select the diff scheme when I get ready to commit.  But I can't figure out the right command.  I would think it would be something like this (in `.gitconfig`):

```
[core]
    editor = C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe /s Diff
```

But Git reads that whole line as the file name and then tells me it can't find the `notepad.exe /s Diff` file anywhere.

How can I get Git to consider the `/s Diff` as a command line option, not part of the file name?

(I'm using Windows 10 and the Windows command prompt.)

Comment: Should `notepad.exe` be `notepad2.exe`? And do you have the correct path to the executable?

Comment: Nah, I used the installation option that replaces Windows Notepad with Notepad2.  It works fine if I omit the command line part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a similar pattern as "[How can I make Sublime Text the default editor for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9408117/6309)"

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe' -s Diff"
```

From "[git: Show index diff in commit message as comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46160765/6309)", it is `-s`, not `/s`.