# How to show `git log` in the editor during `git commit`?

Tags: git, vim, git-commit

I repeatedly caught myself calling `git log` before `git commit` to see what were the last commits before making a new one.

Is there a way how to automatically populate the commented-out section of the `git commit` message in the editor with the output of `git log`? Perhaps even with some options like `-n5`? Right now, it shows the branch and staged files.

Very similar with [git: Show index diff in commit message as comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750148/git-show-index-diff-in-commit-message-as-comment) question but `--verbose` does not show the logs.

I use vim as my editor if it is relevant.

Comment: You can put your cursor anywhere in the commented-out section and do `:read !git log -n5`. See `:help :read`.

Comment: @romainl Interesting solution, it could be even coupled with autocommand on opening the git message file to make it automatic. Thank you.

Comment: You can use  a `prepare-commit-msg` hook to edit the commit message file in place before the editor opens, too. This lets you write arbitrarily complex scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commit message can be customised using the `--edit` and `--file` options. A hyphen can be used with the `--file` option to read additional commit message text from stdin. This didn't work well for me with vim; maybe because it was not invoked as `vim -`.

Bash process substitution seems to work though:

```sh
git commit --edit --file=<(git log -n5 | sed 's/^/# /')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, I will just add an alias for so I do not have to type it every time.